# Rails routes, redirect on script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I need redirect from url "/script.js" to "/assets/folder/script.js"
I try to add

```
  match "/script.js" => 'assets/folder/script.js'
```

But i have

```
ERROR -- : missing :action (ArgumentError)
```

when worker start.
How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#redirection)

```
match "/script.js" => redirect("/assets/folder/script.js")
```

assuming `/assets/folder/script.js` is the url for that script.